# Matlab %#ok comment flags

Tags: matlab, flags

There are many comment flags that appear periodically in Matlab code such as

```
%#ok<SAGROW>
%#ok<INUSD>
%#ok<INUSL>
```

What do these mean?  And more importantly, where can I find a list of all of them?

Comment: See the above question for a link to documentation. The bottom line is you don't need to remember those mlint warning suppressors. They are inserted into the code automatically when you press Ctrl-right click and choose "Suppress...on this line".

Comment: AGROW indicates your array/string grows on each iteration.

Comment: A shame this was marked as duplicate, as the last question (where can I find a list of them) is nowhere answered. There is one comment flag for each Code Analyzer (MLint) warning. Inserting the comment flag after a line with a Code Analyzer warning suppresses it. In the MATLAB preferences, you can set which warnings you wish to display. Any that you set to the non-default value are saved to a file `MLintDefaultSettings.txt` in your preferences directory (type `cd(prefdir)` to get there. To discover a list of all flags, set all your MLint preferences to non-default, save, and look at the file.